# C# changing a value with extension method

Tags: c#

If I have the following extension methods:

```
internal static class Extensions
{
    public static void Increase(this uint value)
    {
        value += 1;
    }

    public static void Decrease(this uint value)
    {
        if (value > 0) value -= 1;
    }
}
```

Why does this not result in a changing `i` to 1?

```
uint i = 0;
i.Increase();
```

Comment: Value types are passed `by-value` to methods, you are operating on copy of that value. Remember that compiler changes `i.foo()` to `StaticClass.foo(i)`, this is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @csharpfolk: *Everything* is passed by-value by default.

Comment: Integers are value types - you're incrementing a copy of your integer, not the actual integer. You'd need to pass your integer as `ref int` to achieve what you're attempting, but extension methods don't allow `ref`.

Comment: There is no reason for the downvote. Your question was clear and reasonable IMO. (It may be a duplicate question, but that's not a good reason for a downvote.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson thank you. I just wanted to ask publicly, see if there was something I should be improving on, with my questions...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The parameter is being passed by value, that's all. There's nothing special about extension methods on this front. It's equivalent to:

```
Extensions.Increase(i);
```

You'd need the method to have the first parameter passed by reference (with `ref`) for that to have any effect... and that's prohibited for extension methods anyway.

So while you could write a method allowing you to call it as:

```
Extensions.Increase(ref i);
```

you won't be able to make that an extension method.

An alternative is to make the method *return* a value, at which point you could have:

```
i = i.Increase();
```

If you're not entirely clear on pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value semantics, you might want to read my [article on the topic](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: "There's nothing special about extension methods on this front." -- Except that for value types, the implicit `this` argument of instance methods does get passed by `ref`, so even though extension methods are intended to emulate the syntax of instance methods, they cannot achieve the same functionality.

Comment: @hvd mutable structs are questionable... So I think extensions methods achive comparable level of "functionality" to cause problems/insane error messages - just in slightly different cases :)

Comment: @JonSkeet That they don't is my point. And that *is* something special about extension methods: when `t` is a value type, ordinarily, in `t.Method()`, `t` *does* get passed by `ref`. It's only with extension methods that it doesn't. But I certainly agree with Alexei's comment that mutating instance methods are not generally a good idea, so there's likely only a few reasons why mutating extension methods might ever be wanted. I've written about that myself in the past. :)

Comment: @hvd: Oh, I see what you mean... although I wouldn't have expressed it that way, and if `t` is a readonly variable, a copy is taken first so it's not really `t` that's passed by reference. I'm going to delete my comment from a few minutes ago, as probably causing more confusion than benefit...

Comment: Nice corner case, I wasn't aware of that one yet.